# Can a photographic film on a flat slab create a well visible elongated picture of a far and faint astronomical object?

Tags: optical-materials, astrophotography

[image]Let say we see a light source with apparent cross section area 1mm squared. If we position a flat slab with inductive high light sensibility at a very small angle to that source one dimension of the source is elongated on that slab so the 1mm of the source length is spread as let say 10cm on the slab. After that operation there is an another operation slightly complicated but I will try to explain:that slab should, after the first operation is done, be used to shine another slab that is positioned in the same way to the first slab as the first slab was to the astronomical source of light. The dimension of the source elongated by the first slab should be paralel with the second slab so we can elongate the other dimension of the picture of the source of light, to finaly get the source picture with real aspect ratio but 10cm squared. My question is this possible not only theoretically? If If so then 100×100 10000 times enlargement!
[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clearly worded. You seem to be mixing questions about optically reactive materials with questions about ray-tracing image locations.   Further, please take a look at "photoelectric effect" to learn why it's not intensity but rather wavelength that matters.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Please,see the picture I recently added to somehow clarify the question....

Comment: A photographic film can react to the applied light, there is only the problem what is the minimum possible brightness what the film can react to....

Comment: Sure, you can spread the light over the slab, but you'll need to increase the exposure time to account for the reduced light per unit area. I don't understand the 2nd slab. I don't think you can do what you want, but maybe a diagram showing the 2 slabs will help us understand what you mean.

Comment: @PM2Ring ok... Give me same time to explain with new picture...

Comment: I fear you still haven't edited sufficiently to meet the "What is the problem you are trying to solve?"  criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very different from how modern imaging systems work.  In general, an imaging system uses a lens or a curved mirror to cause all of the light coming from a particular direction to pass through a particular point; you put your photoreactive detector at that point and learn that that particular direction corresponds to "blue" or "bright green" or "dark."  Usually the focal points for light from different directions are near each other in a "focal plane" that's approximately parallel to the lens; introducing large angles means in general that you have to care about details, like the lens thickness and "chromatic aberration," that are less important in a straight-on configuration.

Your idea of enlarging an image by having an image plane not perpendicular to the light direction might work in a "pinhole camera," for which there isn't really a focal plane.  But a pinhole camera isn't a good low-light detection system, since it works by throwing nearly all of the light away.

Comment: Please, answer if an object with high brightness can be photographed in this way? For example planet Venus...

Comment: For practical advice, search for "pinhole camera" or "camera obscura." Common targets are the Sun, especially during eclipses, and daytime landscapes. A night-sky photo with a pinhole camera would be an interesting challenge.