# Pinhole camera as a device to develope photos of distant stars?

Tags: astronomy, camera, astrophotography

Could a transparent slab coated with photosensitive film be placed inside a pinhole camera nearly paralel to the path of the light emitted by a source of light(star) to produce a picture wich due to the explained position of the slab looks very elongated along one its dimension.Ofcourse it would be ideal to have enough contrast and light for that position of the slab as it would be if the slab were perpendicular to the path of incoming light. So my question is how much the brightness of the picture drops with the change of incident angle of light?This is related to a [closed post.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572547/can-a-photographic-film-on-a-flat-slab-create-a-well-visible-elongated-picture-o)

If it is possible to get a clear picture by this procedure than it could also be possible to elongate the other remaining picture dimension in a second step of the procedure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a pinhole camera can take pictures of distant objects including stars, there are problems with it.

First, light from a star is an expanding spherical wave. A star is light years away. The sphere is light years across when it gets to us. The part of the sphere that passes near us is so flat that it is indistinguishable from a plane wave. Another way to say that is rays of light from a star are parallel. Also the light is dim at large distances.

A pinhole works because it is small. Light from a star that falls on the pinhole will continue in a straight line and hit the film or other sensor. You do get an image of that star the size of your pinhole.

The problem is that stars are dim. Very little light falls on the pinhole. It takes a very long exposure to get a picture.

There is another way. Parallel rays of light that hits a lens come to a focus. If you put film there, you also get a bright spot from the star. But you get a lot more light
because the lens has a larger diameter. And a lens can generally produce a smaller spot than a pinhole. So you shorten the exposure time.

Lenses have other problems. They don't bring all colors of light to a focus at the same distance from the lens. So if green comes to a sharp focus, then blue may be blurry. It is possible to use multiple lenses that compensate for each other.

But there is a better way. Mirrors don't have this problem. And it is possible to make mirrors a lot bigger than a lens. All large professional telescopes use a mirror, or maybe lots of mirrors side by side. This gathers lots of light, and makes it possible to get pictures of very, very faint stars.

Even with large telescopes, faint stars take long exposures. This causes another problem because the Earth turns. You have to turn the telescope to keep it pointing in the same direction, so the star lights up the same point on the film.

With any of these types of telescope, you would want to put the film perpendicular to the light. As you say, if you tilt the film, you get an elongated streak on the film. You really want a point. That point will be more brightly lit than an elongated streak, so it will require a shorter exposure.

Second, from a point, you get a precise measurement of the position of the star. This is important in astronomy.

Third, you usually have more than one star in the picture. Each star lights up a different point on the film. If the film is slanted, the distance isn't right for the other stars to be in focus.